# Image source doesnt change according to the dependencyObject

Tags: wpf, binding, dependencyobject

i'm trying to style my image according to dependancy object i defined as followed:

in MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="GetIsConnected"
                ObjectType="{x:Type ConnectionRepository:ConnectionRepository}" />

    <Image Name="ConnectStatusBarImage" Width="16" Height="16">
        <Image.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/Images/connected16.png" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource GetIsConnected}, Path=IsConnected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Image.Source" Value="/Images/disconnected16.png" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

the repository code looks like that:

```
public class ConnectionRepository : DependencyObject  
    {
    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsConnectedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsConnectedProperty, value); }
    }
}


public static readonly DependencyProperty IsConnectedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IsConnected", 
    typeof(bool), typeof(ConnectionRepository));
```

i set the IsConnect to true if the connection succeeded.

but for some reason the image is not changing according to this object... and idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you are showing `connected16.png` when the object is **not** connected, and switching to `disconnected16.png` when it **is** connected, you would have to set `IsConnected` on the object managed by the ObjectDataProvider:

```
ObjectDataProvider p = (ObjectDataProvider)Resources["GetIsConnected"];
((ConnectionRepository)p.Data).IsConnected = true;
```